# Authentication issue when using azure functions and autodesk forge

Tags: python, azure, autodesk-forge

I am trying to build an azure function in order to get some data from the autodesk forge api and put into a centralised data warehouse. When I test everything locally it is working and updating my tables, however when I deploy as a function to azure I am getting an authentication issue when trying to use a 3 legged token.

I am using this python wrapper: https://github.com/lfparis/forge-python-wrapper/tree/75868b11a3d8bac4b65f66b905c2313a35ba5711/forge

When I run locally, the authentication works fine and I get the access token etc. However when running on azure, instead of being taken to my callback url, it is instead directing me to https://auth.autodesk.com/as/NH3Mc/resume/as/authorization.ping?opentoken=... and so has no access token in the url to extract. Do you know why I might be being redirected here?

This is the section of code which handles the three legged auth

````
        """https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authorize-GET/"""  # noqa:E501
        url = "{}/authorize".format(AUTH_V1_URL)
        params = {
            "redirect_uri": self.redirect_uri,
            "client_id": self.client_id,
            "scope": " ".join(self.scopes),
            "response_type": response_type,
        }
        url = self._compose_url(url, params)
        logger.info('Start url: %s', url)
        chrome_driver_path = os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH")

        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

        google_chrome_path = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
        if google_chrome_path:
            chrome_options.binary_location = google_chrome_path

        try:
            driver = Chrome(
                executable_path=chrome_driver_path,
                chrome_options=chrome_options,
            )
        except (TypeError, WebDriverException):
            chrome_driver_path = chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
            driver = Chrome(
                executable_path=chrome_driver_path,
                chrome_options=chrome_options,
            )

        try:
            driver.implicitly_wait(15)
            driver.get(url)
            logger.info('Start driver url: %s', driver.current_url)
            user_name = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="userName")
            logger.info('Username: %s', self.username)
            user_name.send_keys(self.username)
            verify_user_btn = driver.find_element(
                by=By.ID, value="verify_user_btn"
            )
            verify_user_btn.click()
            logger.info('After first click url: %s', driver.current_url)
            pwd = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="password")
            logger.info('pwd: %s', self.password)
            pwd.send_keys(self.password)
            submit_btn = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="btnSubmit")
            submit_btn.click()
            logger.info('After Password url: %s', driver.current_url)
            allow_btn = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="allow_btn")
            allow_btn.click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(15)
            logger.info('Driver url: %s', driver.current_url)
            return_url = driver.current_url
            driver.quit()

        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(
                "Please provide the correct user information."
                + "\n\nException: {}".format(e)
            )
            "chrome://settings/help"
            "https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads"
            sys.exit()
        logger.info("Return url %s", return_url)
        params = self._decompose_url(return_url)
        logger.info("Returns params from Auth: %s", params)
        self.__dict__.update(params)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that this is an unusual (and likely not officially supported) workflow to obtain a 3-legged token, I'm not even sure if this is a problem on the Autodesk Forge side. It could be some difference between your local Selenium setup, and the setup running in Azure. Have you tried inspecting the HTTP headers sent back and forth when running your Python app in Azure? Any potential differences there could provide more clues as to why you're not being redirected to the expected URL.